# Angular 11: Components and Directives not regognized inside Lazy Loaded Module

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-library, angular-lazyloading

I want to split my angular project to load Website part in main module and application part in lazy loaded module.
While everything worked before, now  I am getting plenty of errors about compoentns and directives not known:

1. Component from same application `<app-downloads-sidebar></app-downloads-sidebar>`:

   Error: projects/nine-gold-tools/src/app/layouts/app-layout/app-layout.component.html:42:13 - error NG8001: 'app-downloads-sidebar' is not a known element:
2. Directives not recognized:
   Error: projects/nine-gold-tools/src/app/layouts/app-layout/app-layout.component.html:58:53 - error

   NG8002: Can't bind to 'dropup' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

   58                     <div dropdown  autoClose="true" [dropup]="true" placement="top" triggers="hover">
3. Library elements (from NineGoldLibModule)

   Error: projects/nine-gold-tools/src/app/application/ramlConverter/raml-converter-page/raml-converter-page.component.html:41:21 - error NG8001: 'lib-file-input' is not a known element:
4. And finally router outlet for subpages

   Error: projects/nine-gold-tools/src/app/layouts/app-layout/app-layout.component.html:93:9 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:

In app-routing I changed from:

```
{ path: 'app', component: AppLayoutComponent, canActivate: [NewAuthGuard], children: [
    { path: 'downloads', component: DownloadsPageComponent, canActivate: [NewAuthGuard] },
    { path: 'raml-converter', component: RamlConverterPageComponent, canActivate: [NewAuthGuard] },
    { path: 'json-converter', component: JsonConverterPageComponent, canActivate: [NewAuthGuard] },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'raml-converter', pathMatch: 'full' }
  ]},
```

to:

{ path: 'app', loadChildren: './application/tools-app.module.ts' },

Inside tools-app.module.ts I declare all compoments (removed declarations from app module) and do only these imports:

```
declarations: [
    DownloadsPageComponent,
    DownloadsSidebarComponent,
    AppLayoutComponent,
    RamlConverterPageComponent,
    RamlConverterSidebarComponent,
    JsonConverterSidebarComponent,
    JsonConverterPageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NineGoldLibModule,
    ToolsAppRoutingModule
]
```

NineGoldLibModule is the workspace library imported also in app-module.ts

And Finally my tools-app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppLayoutComponent, canActivate: [NewAuthGuard], children: [
    { path: 'downloads', component: DownloadsPageComponent, canActivate: [NewAuthGuard] },
    { path: 'raml-converter', component: RamlConverterPageComponent, canActivate: [NewAuthGuard] },
    { path: 'json-converter', component: JsonConverterPageComponent, canActivate: [NewAuthGuard] },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'raml-converter', pathMatch: 'full' }
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ToolsAppRoutingModule { }
```

I cannot find any valid solution for this issue online.

Comment: `{ path: 'app', loadChildren: './application/tools-app.module.ts' }` lazy loading syntax is incorrect

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, what should it be?

Comment: which version of angular are you currently on ?

Comment: `{
    path: 'app',
    loadChildren: () => import('./application/tools-app.module').then(m => m.ToolsAppModule)
  }`

Comment: on which line this error comes? and double check path is correct or not inside import('') in loadChildren

Comment: This loadChildren syntax works for you or not ?

Comment: Still seeing same errors. These errors are inside html template files, whenever any other component is included in html.

Comment: What if you are not lazy-load module for `app` path.. then its working fine or not ?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine without lazy load

Comment: Let me make one demo, see if its working or not..

Comment: Smallest example: I have fontawesome library loading to app.module.. In template file I have  <fa-icon [icon]="downloadIcon"></fa-icon>. This give me error when template is part of lazy loaded module.(fa-icon is not known element)

Comment: can you give me link where I can download and install font awesome inside angular via npm ?

Comment: actually I think I fixed it. The fontawesome error was first on the link. I added FontAwesome to imports in lazy loaded module and it got built.

Comment: Now everything is working fine or not ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Your comments directed me to the solution.  I think that first error in template was like domino effect. It is still strange to me, why I need to load that external library in lazyLoaded module again.

Comment: great!! If you want, then you can buy me a coffee .. https://www.buymeacoffee.com/grdtech And I am also available at email grdtechlab@gmail.com and if you in need to work..

Comment: Think of ngModules as a compilation context. To compile ToolsAppModule it needs all the component modules to be imported in it's module.

Answer (score 0):

After some questions in comments from Gaurang Dhorda, I reviewed errors and the first one was about FontAwesome tag (`<fa-icon>`) I have included FontAwesome package in LazyLoaded module and the build went through.

---

I had another issue, and my solution might help someone, so here it is:

When navigating to Lazy Load route I kept getting BrowserModule already loaded error.
I found that BrowserAnimationsModule cannot be loaded more that once, but it's required in the Library Module and Library module is loaded also for LazyLoaded module. To prevent loading BrowserAnimationsModule twice I added this code in Library module:

```
export class NineGoldLibModule {
  constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: BrowserAnimationsModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
    // skip
    }
  }
}
```

Probably I don't need this if statement.

Everything works now.

Comment: To prevent this You can remove `BrowserAnimationsModule` from library module to `app.module.ts`, so you have only one import of `BrowserAnimationModule`. But, `BrowserModule` is for app.module.ts, and all child moudle have to import `CommonModule` . HttpClientModule also need to import once only in app.module.ts. if we re-import HttpClientModule inside child module then new instance is created and your app has two instance of HttpClient and eventually root interceptors fail to work.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started angular material also doing same and import `BrowserAnimationModule` only once in app.module.ts